# Adjacency list graph in Java

Tags: java, graph

I am reading a text, that from a higher level explained adjacency list implementation of a graph.

I have now tried to implement this as simply as I could. I did not see any reason to have an actual vertex or node class.

Based on my implementation, does it look like I understood properly how an adjacency list graph works?

```
import java.util.*;

public class Graph {
    private HashMap<String, HashSet<String>> nodes;    

    public Graph () 
    {
        nodes = new HashMap<String, HashSet<String>>();
    }

    public void addNode(String name)
    {
        if (!nodes.containsKey(name))
            nodes.put(name ,  new HashSet<String>());
    }

    public void addEdge(String src , String dest)
    {
        HashSet<String> adjList = nodes.get(src);

        if (adjList == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("addEdge - src node does not exist");

        adjList.add(dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a `main()` that exercises this code?  It's not obvious how you can use the generated graph.

Answer (score 1):

I think the code is incomplete. It's possible to build a `Graph` but there is no way to process it as there are no methods returning the state of a `Graph`.

To be able to evaluate the shown code I'm going to extend it by two methods:

```
/**
 * Returns true if a node with the given name was added.
 */
public boolean hasNode(String name) {
    return nodes.containsKey(name);
}


/**
 * Returns true if an edge form source node to destination node (identified by their names) was added.
 */
public boolean hasEdge(String src, String dest) {
    HashSet<String> adjList = nodes.get(src); 
    return adjList != null && adjList.contains(dest);
}
```

Let's use a simple example to show some shortcomings:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Graph g = new Graph();
    g.addNode("A");
    g.addEdge("A", "B");

    System.out.println(g.hasNode("A")); // true
    System.out.println(g.hasNode("B")); // false
    System.out.println(g.hasEdge("A", "B")); // true
}
```

**egdes to missing nodes**
The method `addEdge` verifies that a source node is already present. But it doensn't verify if the destination node is present, too. Thus it's possible to `addEdge` from an already added node to an unknown node.
Whereas `hasNode("B")` will state that there is no node `"B"` in the `Graph g`, `hasEdgde("A", "B")` will return `true` which is at least misleading. I think  it's inconsistent as I would expected this implies there is a node `"B"` also present in the `Graph g`.

**directed graph**
Since `addEdge` adds an edge from a source node to a destination node it's more precise to speak of a directed graph. Otherwise

```
g.hasEdge("B", "A");
```

needs to return `true`. But actually it isn't.

**readding a node is possbile**
Another point: It's possible to add already added nodes again.

```
g.addNode("A");
```

This results in replacing the current node by a new one. There is no exception and `hasNode("A")` will still return `true`. But all edges from the previous node to other nodes are lost.

```
System.out.println(g.hasEdge("A", "B")); // false
```

This should be prevented.

**readding an edge**
Readding an edge doesn't throw an exception. But it doesn't add an edge actually. It's impossible since a node is storing it's edges in a `Set`. A `Set` will not add an already present element once again. As long as there is no need to know how many times an edge from a node to another was add this isn't severe.

Some further hints:

- You can declare `nodes` as `Map<String, Set<String>>`. Since you're using interface methods only, there is no need to use the implementation types.
- When adding a node calling first `nodes.containsKey(name)` and then on success calling `nodes.put(name, new HashSet<String>())` has double complexity as the element within the map has to be looked up twice. But sinnce adding a node several times shouldn't be possible we can write

instead:

```
public void addNode(String name) {
    Set<String> node = nodes.get(name);
    if (node != null)
        throw new RuntimeException("addNode - node already exist");
    nodes.put(name, new HashSet<String>());
}
```